# Use easyzlib.dll in Visual Foxpro

Tags: compression, visual-foxpro, entry-point, dllregistration, entrypointnotfoundexcept

The easyzlib generates a dll file, and a tried to register it, but a error appears.
Then, a create a project in Visual Foxpro for use the ezlib.dll, but other error generates:
"Cannot find entry point ezcompress int the DLL."

This is the test code:

```
    DECLARE Integer ezcompress IN ezlib.Dll;
      unsigned char pDest, long pnDestlen, const unsigned char pSrc, long nSrcLen;
    DECLARE Integer ezuncompress IN ezlib.Dll;
      unsigned char pDest, long pnDestlen, const unsigned char pSrc, long nSrcLen;

    arq = GETFILE('TXT', 'ProcuraR UM txt:.', '', 1, 'Navegar')
    result = ezcompress(0, 0, @arq, 0)

    if(result >= 0)
        ? "Comprimido com sucesso!"

    Read Events
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function names in DECLARE are case-sensitive. Could that be your issue?

For VFP, you also might consider using Craig Boyd's compression library: http://www.sweetpotatosoftware.com/spsblog/2009/08/09/MajorVFPEncryptionUpdate.aspx

Comment: I'm sure the name of the functions are correct.
I'll try use Crayg Boyd's compression library!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I need a exemple using Craig Boyd's for compress a file .TXT!
Thanks

Comment: Here's an article about using the library: http://doughennig.com/papers/..%5CPub%5C201103dhen.pdf